# Condensing bunch of if-else statements in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a ton of if else statements, all changing the value of an object depending on their condition. I would like to know if there is another way to write this code so it can be condensed/simplified and doesn't take up do much space. I have the following code:

```
if (inputOne == "Yes") {
    inputOne = "517"
} else {
    inputOne = "518"
}
if (inputTwo == "Yes") {
    inputTwo = "518"
} else{
    inputTwo = "519"
}
if (inputThree == "Yes") {
    inputThree = "519"
} else {
    inputThree = "520"
}
if (inputFour == "Yes") {
    inputFour = "520"
} else {
    inputFour = "521"
}
```

And so on... I will be changing the value of multiple objects based on their inputs. Are there any other ways to write this in JavaScript that could save time or make it look cleaner?

Comment: Does this help you? https://jsfiddle.net/5fbvf5vy/

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal Hey thank you! This is similar to what I am asking. Is this format acceptable in my JS file? Because this looks a lot cleaner and would love to copy something similar to that format. Thanks again.

Comment: can you please accept this as answer so that it can help other community member, even though it is not the correct place for review :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start you can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

```
inputOne = inputOne == "Yes" ? "517" : "518";
```

Then you could create a function that you can reuse, like...

```
function setInputValue(input, yes, no) {
    input = input == "Yes" ? yes : no;
}
```

and invoke it like...

```
setInputValue(inputOne, "517", "518");
setInputValue(inputTwo, "518", "519");
```

Comment: Are these two different ways of doing this? Meaning, I could either use a ternary on the top (inputOne = inputOne == "Yes" ? "517" : "518";) or create a function that is reusable (such as the one you show underneath) ? Or do I need to perform all these steps for it to work? Thanks in advance

Comment: these are two different methods, second solution is derived from first one.

Answer (score 2):

Using ternary operator you can solve this.
Here is JS fiddle for this: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/5fbvf5vy/

`inputOne == "Yes" ? "517" : "518";
inputTwo == "Yes" ? "518" : "519";
inputThree == "Yes" ? "519" : "520";
inputFour == "Yes" ? "520" : "521";`

Comment: You should really turn this into a function.

Comment: Yup, another answer have done that already, didn't want to duplicate the answer. :-)

Comment: In that case the other answer is superior to yours and there's no point in having yours around as well, right?

Comment: yup let me remove it then